# How to refactor this waterfall of ifs to be more clean and efficient?

Tags: c#, if-statement, numbers, conditional-statements, refactoring

I'm working on my flaw when i write code: i never write clean programs in any language.

So, any suggestion to re-write this piece of code in an "elegant" way? Because I don't like this waterfall of ifs...

```
public float RoundAngle(float angle)
{
    if(angle < 45 && angle >= -45){
        return 0
    }

    if(angle < 135 && angle >= 45){
        return 90
    }

    if(angle < 315 && angle >= 225)
    {
        return 270
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest posting this on codereview.stackexchange if your code is working in this form

Comment: Ohm, ok! Sorry! Thanks! :)

Comment: are you missing 180 degrees, or is this part of the requirement? if 180 is an option too, you could actually use `90 * Math.Round(angle/90)`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes, i forgot to write one if statement!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: _"Because I don't like this waterfall of ifs..."_ - that's not a waterfall

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for improve working code which is off-topic on stackoverflow and better fits on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How about `return (int)((angle + 45) / 90) * 90;` ? This is assuming that 135..225 means 180, 315..405 is 360.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oops, sorry, mistake. Now it works (?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) with some [C# 9 patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements):

```
public float RoundAngle(float angle)
{
    return angle switch
    {
        <45 and >=-45 => 0,
        <135 and >=45 => 90,
        <315 and >=225 => 270,
        _ => SomeDefaultValue,
    };
}
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks, switch case is a good idea!

Comment: I like C# 9's new `and/when` keywords expanding on the usual `&&` etc though it's kinda ironic that everything was made _concise_.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you don't need ifs at all to begin with:

```
var normalizedAngle = 90 * (int)((angle + 405) / 90) % 360;
```

That said, ifs are probably easier to understand

Unless you have a really complicated nested if structure which is hard to read and follow, not your case at all, there is nothing actually wrong with your code. IMHO I think its easier to understand than the one liner option.

Comment: @OlivierRogier then you have done something wrong...

Comment: Truncate to int in there: `(int)((angle + 45) / 90) * 90`.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Ah, I see, `angle` in my code is an `int`, if you are declaring it as `float` you need to truncate it. My bad.

Comment: @.InBetween Now that works! (except for out of managed cases over and below)

Comment: @OlivierRogier fixed that, simplified the equation.